# What is this part of the website's design?

Tags: support, design

I came to see the bottom of the main website page, for once, and I must say I'm troubled: I don't know what the following image represents.

[image]

It looks like snow next to a schematic pump or something with 2 of the 3 parts floating in the air? Is it an obvious reference to any popular movie/shows like the ones under the website names?

So if someone could enlighten me, I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a spilled **popcorn** container...

[image]

It's similar to the one in our main logo at the top the page

[image]

Comment: Oh damn! Now I see it, I feel dumb having asked this. I really couldn't see it... :( Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, I needed to see it twice to get it too, because since the ground is blue, I first thought it was something water related.